# How to suppress fputs, fsockopen etc warnings without disabling error reporting?

Tags: php, fputs

I use fsockopen, fgets and fputs to implement communication protocol with other machine. NetBeans give warning to all '@' before `fsockopen, fputs, fgets` etc. The solution works but without '@' after disconnection of remote device there are warnings (not errors).

I don't want to use error_reporting because it is not more kosher solution. Additionally more code, longer execution time...

Is there any better solution for this?

BTW. the warnings occurs if the destination machine will drop connection. It is possible if device is overload.

```
$answer=@fgets($socket, $negotiatedMaxLength);
```

BTW. The solution should work without `ini_set` - blocked on server and without `error_reporting()`.

Comment: Could you use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead?

Comment: Will it work for TCP/IP connection? All functions fgets, fputs, fsockopen can be replaced with other but... It is TCP/IP, not file.

Comment: For many things, yes. [Without seeing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) however it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way instead of `@` which is obvious way to do it, is to use `set_error_handler`

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_set_error_handler.asp

This lets you pipe the errors into the `ErrorException` class and then you have exceptions instead of errors. That's allows you to use `try/catch` blocks for the errors.

```
set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file = 'Unknown', $line = 'Unknown'){
     //typically I set a constant for PHP_ERRORS for the exception code.
     if (error_reporting() != -1 && !(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
         //we'll let this error go to the next error handler
         return; //return null
     }else{
          //convert the error into an exception
         throw new ErrorExcption($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line );
         //we don't have to return anything because the exception throwing kicks us out of the error handler.
     } 
 });

 try{
     $answer=fgets($socket, $negotiatedMaxLength);
 }catch(ErrorException $e ){

 }
```

Note the `&` single ampersand is intentional for checking severity level -vs- error reporting level you do `bitwise And`

Also the `$file` and `$line` are optional, so we set a default for them.

Comment: I will try it on Sunday or Saturday. If it will work correctly with good performance I guess +1. BTW. New exception is there not needed. No answer means error and is handled.

Comment: I try also "try...catch" but in the past it doesn't catch this warning on fputs.

Comment: because it's a warning, but you can turn it into an exception by trowing the ErrorException from the error handler.  Which is  sort of the whole point.

Comment: @18C - I cleaned it up a bit and had to go look at some code I use this in to be sure... should be good now.

Comment: It is very kosher solution for warnings that shall be also catch in application. If the error handler is no longer needed: `bool restore_error_handler(void)` can be used to remove it and set previous handler (probably PHP default handler). Thank you.

Comment: I use a uniform error / exception / shutdown handler for all my sites to log errors and email me on fatal errors.